# Question about Maven Publish Gradle plugin?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

A lot of the former DevOps and devs that set up my company's Gradle infrastructure have left before I came on board, and so no one currently knows a lot of what they did. I'm a Maven guy trying to learn Gradle so I have a few questions that no one in my company seem to know the answer to. For example, I have the following in a `build.gradle`

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'artifactId': artifactId,
                      'groupId': project.group,
                      'version': project.version
    }
    baseName artifactId
}
publishing {
    publications {
        coreComponent(MavenPublication) {
            artifactId artifactId
            from components.java
        }
    }
}
```

Normally I expect to see `maven(MavenPublication) {}` but why `coreComponent(MavenPublication) {}`? Where/what/how do I find out what `coreComponent` is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Normally I expect to see `maven(MavenPublication) {}` but why `coreComponent(MavenPublication) {}`? Where/what/how do I find out what `coreComponent` is?

It is just the name of the publication and it is only important if your project has multiple publications that may be published separately. Gradle transforms the statement `coreComponent(MavenPublication) {...}` into a call to the method [`create(String name, Class<U> type, Action<? super U> configuration)`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/PolymorphicDomainObjectContainer.html#create-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-org.gradle.api.Action-) of the [`PublicationContainer`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/publish/PublicationContainer.html). The call creates a new publication of the type [`MavenPublication`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.publish.maven.MavenPublication.html) and with the name `'coreComponent'` and configures it using the passed `configuration`.

You can choose any name for the publication, it is mainly used to generate the name of the publication tasks, e.g. `publish<PubName>PublicationToMavenLocal`. Call `gradle tasks` on your project and you will see that it contains a task called `publishCoreComponentPublicationToMavenLocal`. Since a lot of projects only have a single publication, they use `'maven'` as publication name, but it is far from a real convention.

A similar mechanism is used for publication repositories, as any publication may be published to multiple repositories. Internally, there is a another (older) API for repositories, so you cannot use the notation `<name>(<Type>)` as above. Instead, you may create repositories of type [`MavenArtifactRepository`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/repositories/MavenArtifactRepository.html) using the method [`maven()`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/dsl/RepositoryHandler.html#maven-org.gradle.api.Action-) and assign them names using the configuration action:

```
publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
            name = 'bintray'
            // ...
        }
        maven {
            name = 'github'
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Gradle then creates a publication task for each combination of a `MavenPublication` and a `MavenArtifactRepository` with the name `publish<PubName>PublicationTo<RepoName>Repository`, resulting in the tasks `publishCoreComponentPublicationToBintrayRepository` and `publishCoreComponentPublicationToGithubRepository`.